# Installing python modules so I can use it anywhere

Tags: python, pip

I cloned https://github.com/deepmind/spiral.git to ~/spiral and installed the python module. I can only use it at ~/spiral. How do I use it in other directories?

Comment: drop in the the directory where the other modules are, site_packages or whatever

Comment: You can use `pip install .` inside the project directory to install it.

Comment: @SuperStew You do not always have access to site_packages modules and should not have. I'd ideally create a virtual environment then run `pip install . -e --user` to install inside the virtual environment and for a particular user. It is okay to not use virtual environment here

Comment: @mad_ venvs are for chickens. go all in #yolo

Comment: @mad_ ,a_guest: If you'd copy that into the answer section, maybe add some details or documentation - wouldn't those be answers rather than comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the README from the repo, here are the steps to install the module:

1. Clone the repo to a directory and update all the submodules:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/deepmind/spiral.git
cd spiral
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

2. Install the dependencies:

```sh
apt-get install cmake pkg-config protobuf-compiler libjson-c-dev intltool libpython3-dev python3-pip
pip3 install six setuptools numpy scipy tensorflow==1.14 tensorflow-hub dm-sonnet==1.35
```

3. Install the package itself:

```sh
python3 setup.py develop --user
```

4. To be able to run `libmypaint` and `Fluid paint` properly, you need to run:

```sh
wget -c https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint-brushes/archive/v1.3.0.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz -C third_party
git clone https://github.com/dli/paint third_party/paint
patch third_party/paint/shaders/setbristles.frag third_party/paint-setbristles.patch
```

**Edit**: Updated the steps needed to install the package

Comment: python setup.py install only imports to spiral.environments I can't import fluid or libmypaint

Comment: The README file of the repo actually shows how to install the module, I hadn't see it the first time. I've updated my post with the steps to follow to install it properly.